# Как изменить число в центре иконки кластера на Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, карты, кластеризация

Столкнулся с проблемой, которую не пойму, как решить. Проблема в следующем. Для увеличения скорости выгрузки меток на карту выгружаем вместо 20 000 меток рандомную 1000 меток и их кластеризуем. Всё получается прекрасно, кроме одного. Если сложить числа в центре иконок кластеров, то получается 1000, а надо, чтобы 20 000. То есть надо искусственно изменить числа на иконках кластеров, скажем, увеличив на рассчитанный коэффициент. Это возможно сделать? Если кто-то знает как, хотя бы намекните! Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

У объекта Marker есть метод - [setLabel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Marker.setLabel)

Используя его можно установить новое значение.

```
marker.setLabel(ваше число)
или
marker.setLabel({
 text: ваше число,
})
```

label - строка, т.е. не забудьте перевести число в строку

Заранее посчитайте количество меток и установите.